# PyQt5 Signal Slot not working

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots

First of all, here's my code:

```
class PyQtObject(object):
    class __PyQtObject(QObject):
        my_signal = pyqtSignal()

        def __init__(self):
            QObject.__init__(self)
            self.my_signal.connect(self.my_slot)

        @pyqtSlot()
        def my_slot(self):
            print("call")

        def call_in_main_thread(self):
            print("should call")
            print(self)
            self.my_signal.emit()

    instance = None

    def __init__(self):
        if PyQtObject.instance is None:
            PyQtObject.instance = PyQtObject.__PyQtObject()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.instance, name)
```

And here is how it's supposed to work:

I'm creating a PyQt Window with a textbox, which receives frequent updates by another thread, adding lines to it.
This results in wonky output, because elements of `QWidgets` should not be changed outside the PyQt Main Thread.
You can work around this by emitting a signal, which is connected to a slot, which in turn adds the lines to the text field.

Now when you have a setup like that in a lot of places it made sense to me, to outsource it to a function which does the signal emitting, and calls the function from the slot. Above code is what I came up with.

Now here's the problem, this is the resulting output:

```
should call
<object at ...ABCDEF>
call
should call
<object at ...ABCDEF>
...
should call
<object at ...ABCDEF>
call
```

As you can see, the slot is only called occasionally. I can count exactly 3 calls until it just stops being called at all. The three calls have a lot of signal emissions before them, except for the first one. The object is printed to make sure no local variables are memory cleaned before the slot can be called.

What is going wrong here? Things I've tested:

- re-connecting the slot to the signal changes nothing.
- adding multithreading at various places didn't change anything.
- Singleton pattern.

I'm really at a loss here

---

*update* I tried a new approach with two options:

```
caller_objects = []

class CallerObject(QObject):
    signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, func: callable, args: tuple = None, kwargs: dict = None):
        import threading

        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signal.connect(self.slot)

        # option 1
        self.signal.emit()
        # option 2
        threading.Thread(target=self.signal.emit).start()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def slot(self):
        print("call")
        global caller_objects
        if self.kwargs is not None:
            if self.args is not None:
                self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            else:
                self.func(**self.kwargs)
        elif self.args is not None:
            self.func(*self.args)
        else:
            self.func()
        caller_objects.remove(self)


def call_in_main_thread(func: callable, args: tuple = None, kwargs: dict = None):
    global caller_objects
    caller_objects.append(CallerObject(func, args, kwargs))
```

Option 1 results in an instant non-catchable crash.
Option 2 results in the slot being called *sometimes*. I have literally no idea when, or why, but when I click around in the GUI sometimes it gets called. Lines get added, `call` in the log.

So weird